# Exercise proof that the function is holomorphic

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I am trying to solve the following problem:

Given the function $F(z, \xi) := \frac{\xi +z}{\xi -z},$ (which, when we fix $\xi$ and interpret it as a function of $z$ is obviosly holomorphic for $z \neq \xi$) and a real, continuous function f, show that the integral
$\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{|\xi|=R} F(z, \xi) f(\xi) \frac{d \xi}{\xi}$ is holomorphic for any $|z|<R$.

My question is, if there even is anything to prove, because we integrate over $\xi$, not over $z$ (since the integral of a holomorphic function in general is not always holomorphic).

What confuses me though, is that if we integrate over $\xi$, $F$ will still change, since it is a function of $\xi$ and $z$.
I would appreciate any clues.

Comment: Are you familiar with Morera's theorem?

Comment: No, I looked it up, but I do not think I have seen it before. What does it have to do with the proof?

Comment: There is certainly *something* to prove: that your integral (call it I(z)) is holomorphic for |z| < R.  For instance, you could show that I(z) is differentiable when |z| < R. Or you could show that I(z) equals a power series whose radius of convergence is ≥ R. Or you could show that its integral around any closed curve is zero when |z| < R. (Morera's theorem says it suffices to show merely that its integral around any triangle is zero.)